# a help need in Jquery

Tags: jquery

the problem is that the code i used is only removing the ".now" class. I wanted that ".year_line" class hav to be replaced by ".now" class by clicking the anchor tag.

```
                <div class="tym_line">
                <ul>
                <li class="now"><a href="#">Now</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2009</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2006</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2005</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2004</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2003</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2002</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">2001</a></li>
                <li class="year_line"><a href="#">Born</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>                  


         JQuery code:


           $('.tym_line').on('click', 'li', function() {
           $(this)
        .removeClass('year_line')     
               .addClass('now')
      .removeClass('now')         
              .addClass('year_line');

             return false;
          });
```

Comment: Please make your question description clear, and also please make sure you post something you've tried.  You are not in a hurry are you?

Comment: yup i have tried but its getting only partialy correct but there is a problm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.tym_line').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this)
        .removeClass('year_line')
        .addClass('now')
        .siblings()
            .removeClass('now')
            .addClass('year_line');

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Ny4y/10/

Although you can 'do away with' the class `year_line` as you could simply use the CSS selector

```
.tym_line li
```

or

```
.tym_line li:not(.now)
```

In this case, you can reduce the JS snippet to:

```
$('.tym_line').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass('now')
        .siblings()
            .removeClass('now');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: THANKS MAN U R A LIFE SAVER .......

Comment: @user1213684 Please stop using "CAPS" it hurts eyes..